# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT doesn't return all results

Tags: mysql, group-concat

i've used GROUP_CONCAT to get results splitted by comma (`,`), but when i saw, the `GRUP_CONCAT` returned only **205** splitted numbers, but in the database there's **2448** results (different `aid`). Here is my query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`aid`) As favoriti 
FROM `z_web_favoriti` 
WHERE `kup_id`='1' AND `pos_id`='571'
```

When i execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `aid` 
FROM `z_web_favoriti` 
WHERE `kup_id`='1' AND `pos_id`='571'
```

I get the following result: ***Showing rows 0 - 29 (2448 total,..)***

Anyone has some solution why it isn't working?
*I've searched on stackoverflow for similar problem, but i couldn't find it..*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you have exceeded [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) maximum length.

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me when I used as multiplies **1024** with any number
Ex: I used **1024*100=102400**
`SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 102400`

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code.

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`aid`) As favoriti 
FROM `z_web_favoriti` 
WHERE `kup_id`='1' AND `pos_id`='571'
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation ` - can this be changed through `ini` files?

Comment: @Ultrazz008 just try with `SET group_concat_max_len=15000;`

Comment: Successfull executed, but the same result, even if i setted to 30000.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the maximum length for `group_concat()` is 1,024.

You can change this to a larger value by changing the value of the system variable `group_concat_max_len`.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) explains this.